# SELECT STATEMENT using multiple columns

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem with this query.

I want to search in Column4 like example "Ongoing"

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Column4 FROM Table WHERE Column1 ='" + textBox1.Text + "', Column2 ='" + textBox2.Text + "'AND Column3 ='" + textBox3.Text + "'" , conn);
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL-Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Also use the debugger to take a look at the resulting statement. Even forgetting about the critical issue of SQL injection, `WHERE Column1 = 'A', Column2 = 'B' AND Column3 = 'C'` is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 1):

first this will lead to `sql injection`, its not good way to code ,

second query have issue : - as there is no `and` condition on column2 and there is no space between column 2 and column 3 `and` condtion

```
"SELECT Column4 FROM Table WHERE Column1 ='" + textBox1.Text + "', 
Column2 ='" + textBox2.Text + "'AND Column3 ='" + textBox3.Text + "'"
```

query should be

```
"SELECT Column4 FROM Table WHERE Column1 ='" + textBox1.Text +
                     "' and Column2 ='" + textBox2.Text + 
                      "' AND Column3 ='" + textBox3.Text + "'"
```

and make use of sqlcommand with sql-parameter and avoid `sql injection`

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on coding your SQL query in that way*, then at least use string formatting:

```
//older style of string format
var query1 = string.Format("SELECT Column4 FROM Table WHERE Column1 = '{0}' AND Column2 = '{1}' AND Column3 = '{2}'"
                           , textBox1.Text
                           , textBox2.Text
                           , textBox3.Text);

//newer style of string format
var query2 = $"SELECT Column4 FROM Table WHERE Column1 = '{textBox1.Text}' AND Column2 = '{textBox2.Text}' AND Column3 = '{textBox3.Text}'";
```

String concatenation the way you did it is going to lead to code that is very hard to read and maintain, and leads to easy mistakes like the `AND` you missed from your `WHERE`.

*as already mentioned by others, direct value injection into a query is a Bad Thing®. However if you're just throwing together a quick and nasty demo where you are the only one using it then it's okay. Just don't do it in production code, not ever.